# IDE for inserting a new record in a xcdatamodel (Core data)?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I just want to ask, is there any way to insert a new record (not programatically) using xcode?

Just to be clear, I want to insert data just like using SQL Developer in Oracle (no code).

I can't find add new record or row button in xcode.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not within XCode but there is a plugin for Firefox that allows you to open the SQLite database. Install the plugin, launch it and open the database file (in the app directory of your iOS simulator) and it provides you with tools to insert, delete, update, etc.

Firefox plugin: [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/)

Comment: The question is about xcdatamodel. Your solution will work only upon sqlite database. But, My knowledge is very limited on this. So, may be you are right.

Comment: xcdatamodel isn't a database. It is a data model. It has to be backed by a database. The default is SQLite (I don't know if you can replace it with something else). So for the default case this will definitely work. I've done it.

Comment: As I said, Limited knowledge on that. Thanks for correcting me :)

Answer (score 0):

No, Xcode doesn't include such a tool, but there is an App that provides a GUI to manage your coredata-backed apps (both iOS and OSX)...
**BUT:**

1. It's a commercial app (costs money)
2. You cannot create or connect relationships between entities (at least, last time I checked)

Having said that, in case you're still interested in this solution, the App is called **[Core Data Editor](http://christian-kienle.de/CoreDataEditor)** and [here is a link](https://itunes.apple.com/gr/app/core-data-editor/id403025957?mt=12) for it in the appstore.